# How to run C programs simultaneously in gcc version 4.8.3 on windows as shown in the introduction chapter in the book OS-ThreeEasySteps?

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: cpu <string>\n");
    exit(1);
}
char *str = argv[1];
while (1) {
   printf("%s\n", str);
   Spin(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
>>gcc -o cpu cpu.c -Wall
>>cpu A & cpu B & cpu C & cpu D
```

Output I got:

```
A
A
A
A
^CB
B
B
B
^CC
C
C
^CD
D
D
^C
```

But, the expected output as shown is the book is different.
The programs are being executed sequentially and not simultaneously. What arguments am I missing?
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: When you run multiple instances at the same time, there's no single "expected" output - the order of output can vary/intermingle. What the book showed is *a* possible output and what you're getting different and both are fine.

Comment: So, is there a way where we can show that these are being executed simultaneously?

Comment: As you can see that A, B, C, & D are printed simultaneously. So they're running simultaneously. Isn't that enough to "show"?

Comment: The programs are not being executed simultaneously.  The first one runs until the OP hits control-C, which kills the first program, then the second one runs, and so on.  This is because the `&` character at a Windows command prompt does not mean "run this program in the background".  The book assumes that you're using a Unix command line, where `&` does mean "run in background".  To get a Unix command line on Windows, install something like Cygwin or Git For Windows and launch their terminal window program.  Or use WSL if your Windows has it.

Comment: @ottomeister so there isn't a way in windows to do that?

Comment: In Windows you can use `start /b` to run a program in the background, and use `&` to separate multiple commands on a single line (that's what `&` means in Windows).  In this case it would look something like `start /b "one" .\cpu A & start /b "two" .\cpu B & start /b "three" .\cpu C & start /b "four" .\cpu D`.  But if the examples in your book are using Unix command syntax, you're going to struggle to find the Windows equivalents for more complex commands (if the equivalents even exist -- the Unix command line has many more features than the Windows command prompt).

Comment: @ottomeister will try it out..thanks...

Comment: @ottomeister I Installed Cygwin and programs are running simultaneously. But, I am not able to stop them using Ctrl+C. It just keeps on looping and there is not enough time to get the background process id to kill or to even type the command. Sure I can close it directly and reopen it but will have navigate to the directory. Or I can just put the files in its directory. But, I  was wondering if there was any shortcut to end those processes.

Comment: I have added Cygwin to the context menu..that will make things easier.

Comment: The `Spin(1)` call is supposed to make the process wait for a second, I imagine, so you should have some time to see the process IDs.  If that's too fast then changing it to `Spin(4)` might help.  Or you can use the "job ID" (1, 2, 3, 4) to kill the processes: `kill %1`, `kill %2` and so on.  Or use the `fg` command to bring each process in turn to the foreground where a control-C will kill it.  Or open a second terminal and kill the processes from there: use `ps` to find the process IDs and `kill ID` to kill them.